# Android update and android mod

Tags: adb, stock-android, fastboot, ota-update

I want to create a custom boot image for my Android. When I will update the System OTA I will lose my mod?

Answer (score 0):

That very much depends on the OTA and what it includes: it might only replace/add some files, but it could as well replace an entire partition (usually `/boot` and/or `/system`).

So yes, an OTA system update *might* overwrite your "custom boot image" – though not all OTAs will do so.